# Animate route change with react-router v3 and transisReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to animate on route leave and enter with react-router 3 and transisReactCSSTransitionGroup. 
My code looks something like this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { browserHistory, Router } from 'react-router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

    class AppContainer extends Component {
      static propTypes = {
        routes : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        store  : PropTypes.object.isRequired
      }

      shouldComponentUpdate () {
        return false
      }

      render () {
        const { routes, store } = this.props
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
              <Router history={browserHistory} children={routes} />
            </div>
          </Provider>
        )
      }
    }

    export default AppContainer
```

route index file:

```
import CoreLayout from '../layouts/CoreLayout'
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'
import NewsRoute from './News'


export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path        : '/',
  component   : CoreLayout,
  indexRoute  : Home,
  childRoutes : [
    NewsRoute(store),
    About,
  ]
})
```

I understand that I need to clone the ReactCSSTransitionGroup component with the location.pathname in my main component.
Something like:

```
 <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName="example"
  transitionAppear={true}
  transitionAppearTimeout={1000}
  transitionLeaveTimeOut={1000}
 >
    {
      React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
        key: location.pathname}
      )
    }
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to achieve that with my current setup.